# Can I use form inputs to filter mongoose data?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm trying to use form input checkboxes to filter through some data in my database with Expressjs. My data looks like this:

```
{ 
"location" : "PHARMACY",
"region" : "SOCAL",
"system" : "WITS",
"contact" : "SMITH",
"membership" : "TIER1" 
},
{ 
"location" : "PHARMACY",
"region" : "NORCAL",
"system" : "SET",
"contact" : "PARSON",
"membership" : "TIER1" 
}
```

And I want to be able to select checkboxes with different options for `location`, `region`, `system`, etc. and then have the entire database entry displayed. So for example if I selected PHARMACY, it would display the above information. Or if I selected SOCAL, it would only display the first entry because it's the only one out of the two that contains SOCAL.

My GET route looks like this, but i'm not sure what to put in `Environment.find()` to make it "find" all of the selected values from the checkboxes:

```
app.get("/environments/show", function(req, res) {
  Environment.find(req.body, function(err, foundEnvironment) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      //render show template with that env
      res.render("show", { environment: foundEnvironment });
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mongoose use user input to find results in DB with express.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60400885/mongoose-use-user-input-to-find-results-in-db-with-express-js)

Comment: What you're doing should work if `req.body` is an object with ONLY attributes that match with your `Environment` model. What is currently happening?

Comment: @SpeedOfRound no it dosnt work, because the body in `GET` requests should be ignored and the output should not be manipulated based on the body data.

Comment: Oh you're right, Emily you should probably build this as a POST request, since your inputs are variable. Otherwise, you'd need to add the searchable fields in your url params like `/environments/show/:location/:region` which I wouldn't recommend. Get requests shouldn't (can't?) utilize req.body.

Comment: @SpeedOfRound ah okay I see, I wasn't aware of that about GET requests... I'll mess around and see if I can get it working with a POST request. Thank you!